# Why is UIResponder inputAccessoryView atomic?

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uiresponder

I'm using `inputAccessoryView` for one of my custom subclasses of `UIViewController`, which subclasses `UIResponder`.

The [Apple Developer Class Reference for `-[UIResponder inputAccessoryView]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIResponder/inputAccessoryView) states:

> Subclasses that want to attach custom controls to either a
>   system-supplied input view (such as the keyboard) or a custom input
>   view (one you provide in the `inputView` property) should redeclare [the `inputAccessoryView`] property as `readwrite` and use it to manage their custom accessory
>   view.

1. After redeclaring `inputAccessoryView`, must I then `@synthesize` it? Doing so seemed to be the only way to get it to compile, but I want to use Apple's `inputAccessoryView` ivar, not synthesize my own.
2. Can I redeclare `inputAccessoryView` as `nonatomic`?
3. If I cannot redeclare `inputAccessoryView` as `nonatomic`, then must I always to access `inputAccessoryView` with `self.inputAccessoryView`, i.e., via the property instead of directly accessing the ivar, in order to preserve thread safety?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you'll have to provide a setter for the property yourself, unless UIResponder exposes a `setInputAccessoryView:` method. If you had access to the underlying ivar, you could just write a setInputAccessoryView: method yourself which sets it. In this case, though, you don't have access to it, so you'll have to create one yourself.
2. I don't think so; this wouldn't be compatible with the superclass declaration.
3. I don't understand why this property is not `nonatomic`, since calling (nearly) anything in UIKit from a non-main thread is invalid. In particular, this property is a `UIView`, and there's no way for the setter to retain and release `UIView`s on a non-main thread safely.

   In other words, if the setter is being called from a background thread, the code is broken either way. If it's only called from the main thread, you can access the ivar directly. So, there's no reason you can't access the ivar directly.

Comment: Especially point 3 made me wonder myself - does not make sense at all.

Comment: Lack of the "`nonatomic`" keyword does *not* mean the implementation is threadsafe.

Comment: True, though I'd expect them to see `nonatomic` for anything that isn't expected to be used from multiple threads.

Comment: Certain interactions with UIKit were made threadsafe in iOS 4.0, like the drawing that David Duncan refers to here: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/296299-drawing-thread-safety-in-ios.html , but I'm not sure if that's relevant here.

Comment: True, @BradLarson, I've updated my language to be more accurate. :)

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll just access it with `self.inputAccessoryView` just to be safe.